# Error while handling environment variables Flask project App Engine and Cloud Build

Tags: flask, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-build

In order to handle the environment variables for my Flask project hosted on Google App Engine I created a cloudbuild.yaml file

```
steps:
- name: 'gcr.io/google.com/cloudsdktool/cloud-sdk'
  entrypoint: 'bash'
  args: ['-c', 'gcloud config set project myprojectid && gcloud       config set app/cloud_build_timeout 1600 && gcloud app deploy --project=myprojectid']
  env:
    - 'CAPTCHA_PUBLIC_KEY=$_CAPTCHA_PUBLIC_KEY'
    - 'CAPTCHA_PRIVATE_KEY=$_CAPTCHA_PRIVATE_KEY'
- name: 'gcr.io/google.com/cloudsdktool/cloud-sdk'
  entrypoint: 'bash'
  args: ['-c', 'gcloud datastore indexes create index.yaml']
  timeout: '1600s'
```

I am using Cloud Build to create the pipelinge between github and my GCP project, but I'm facing an issue while building :

> Step #0: ERROR: gcloud crashed (FileNotFoundError): [Errno 2] No such
> file or directory: '/workspace/myproject/bin/python3'

Can someone help me fix this or at least give me a better way to handle secrets and env. variables with App Engine ? Ty

Comment: It's confuse. WHy did you talk about credentials.yaml. I don't see this file. Why a python error, you don't invoke Python here?

Comment: Yes my mistake, it's cloudbuild.yaml